# Intersection of conjugate sets on $H\leq GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: group-theory

Define $N=\bigcap\limits_{g\in G}(gHg^{-1})$, and let $G=(GL_2(\mathbb{Q}),\cdot)$, and $H=\left\{\bigg[\begin{array}[h]{11}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{array}\bigg]\bigg|\:ab\neq0\right\}$.

Note that $\cdot$ is ordinary matrix multiplication, and  $H\leq G$. I am trying to determine the elements in $N$, though I am having difficulty where to start. I understand the concept of an indexed intersection of sets, although I am clueless as to the criteria for **which elements are in each $gHg^{-1}$?**

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you see what happens with some specific $g$. For example, calculate $gHg^{-1}$ with $g = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$, and then calculate $H \cap gHg^{-1}$. That might help you find the correct answer.

Comment: You could also use the fact that $H$ is finitely generated by the identity matrix.